# Cant set variable outside of php foreach statment

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

I am trying to get `$leadsource` to print or echo outside of the foreach statement but it isnt working.

If I echo `$leadsource` inside of the foreach statement like so `www.test.com?id=2462` it works but if i try to echo $leadsource outside of the foreach statement, which is what I need to happen, it returns the wrong value in the array. This is driving me nuts, any help anyone can give me I would appreciate it.

```
$sourcetracking=$_GET['id'];

$LegacyIDLookupArray = array(
    '2612' => 'ADV-ShowProg',
    '2462' => 'ADV-ShowProg-3.5x7',
    '2422' => 'ADV-Mag-book'
    );


if (!empty($sourcetracking))
{
    foreach ($LegacyIDLookupArray as $LegacyID => $Oldleadsource)
    {
        if ($sourcetracking == $LegacyID)
        { 
            $leadsource = &$Oldleadsource;
            // echo "$leadsource\n"; Echoing $leadsource here works properly.             
        }        
    }
}
else
{
    echo "fail";
}

echo "$leadsource\n"; // echoing $leadsource here echo's the wrong one in the array.
```

Comment: its coming into the array and for each statement by this: www.test.com?id=2462. Id is equaling $sourcetracking. Then it looks it up in the array and finds the matching number and returns the associating value.

Comment: Why the & inn front of $Oldleadsource? Do you really want to create a reference instead of just copying the current value?

Comment: @Rasclatt If this works how I think it does, `$leadsource` should only be set the once. Try adding a `break;` where your echo is inside your foreach loop

Comment: so if id comes in like this www.test.com?id=2462 it finds 2462 in the array and returns ADV-ShowProg-3.5x7. But it only returns the correct value only if i echo leadsource inside of the foreach statement

Comment: i dont actually want to echo $leadsource in the array. I am just echoing $leadsource in the foreach statement to see if its working how i want it to work. What I really need to happen is get the right value to echo outside of the foreach statement

Comment: I modified my answer a bit with some extra bits incase you find it valuable. Nothing that is related to your problem, just some extra checks and maybe some efficiencies...cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting in a break.

```
// As a side note: you can check at the very beginning to see that
// the ID isn't being compromised by something by checking if 
// is_numeric. Also, you can save your 'fail' message until the very
// end when checking that your $leadsource isset. These extra points
// are not essential, but they will throw a fail at all points of the 
// code (if that is valuable at all to you)

$sourcetracking = (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))? $_GET['id']:false;

if($sourcetracking !== false) {
    $LegacyIDLookupArray = array(
        '2612' => 'ADV-ShowProg',
        '2462' => 'ADV-ShowProg-3.5x7',
        '2422' => 'ADV-Mag-book'
        );

         foreach ($LegacyIDLookupArray as $LegacyID => $Oldleadsource) { 
              if($sourcetracking == $LegacyID) { 
                   $leadsource = &$Oldleadsource;

                   // This is where the break goes to stop your loop
                   // when condition is met
                   break;            
               }
          }
    }

// Your $leadsource OR fail is echoed here.
echo (isset($leadsource))? $leadsource : "fail";
```

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure it the passing by reference was important or not, so I went with a solution that includes as much of the original as possible

Comment: Hartmut I did $Oldleadsource = &leadsource; because doing what I was orginially trying to do wasnt working: This was the orginial code

Comment: $sourcetracking=$_GET['id'];

$LegacyIDLookupArray = array(
    '2612' => 'ADV-ShowProg',
    '2462' => 'ADV-ShowProg-3.5x7',
    '2422' => 'ADV-Mag-book'
    );


if (!empty($sourcetracking)) {  
            foreach ($LegacyIDLookupArray as $LegacyID => $leadsource) { 
                    if($sourcetracking == $LegacyID) { 
                        $leadsource = $_POST['LeadSource'];
                                  
                    }
                }
}else {
    echo"fail";
}

   echo $leadsource;

Answer (score 0):

```
original code:
$sourcetracking=$_GET['id'];

$LegacyIDLookupArray = array(
    '2612' => 'ADV-ShowProg',
    '2462' => 'ADV-ShowProg-3.5x7',
    '2422' => 'ADV-Mag-book'
    );


if (!empty($sourcetracking)) {  
            foreach ($LegacyIDLookupArray as $LegacyID => $leadsource) { 
                    if($sourcetracking == $LegacyID) { 
                        $leadsource = $_POST['LeadSource'];
                        break;            
                    }
                }
}else {
    echo"fail";
}

// You may want to do a check to make sure it is set or you will
// get a variable not found error. Even if you think it should be
// set 100% of the time, you just never know. May as well put the 
// isset in.
if(isset($leadsource)) {
   echo $leadsource;
    }
```

Comment: After Id/$sourcetracking runs through the array and finds the matching variables I need if($sourcetracking == $LegacyID) { } to set $leadsource with the variable found in the array so I can then continue with the rest of the form logic

Comment: Did you see if the break works? There shouldn't be a problem passing reference if the break works.